# Javascript Walkcycle on Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to have a "walkcycle" on scroll. So every 10 pixels scrolled, the image should change to the next one.
This was my approach but it is very buggy, wenn you scroll fast because it is only triggers the function when the scroll offset has a full decimal number:

```
var image = 1;
$(window).scroll(function()
{
  windowScrollCount   = $(this).scrollTop();
   animationFrame      = (windowScrollCount / 8);


if (animationFrame % 1 == 0) {
if(image == 1){
    $('.walk').attr('src','img/walk1.svg');
    image = 2;
  } else if(image == 2){
    $('.walk').attr('src','img/walk2.svg');
    image = 1;

} else {}});
```

I hope somebody has an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        img {
            position:fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        #scrollDiv {
            height:1000px;
        }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <img src="" class="walk"></img>
    <div id="scrollDiv"></div>
    <script>
        var imageArr = ["test1.jpg","test2.jpg","test3.jpg","test4.jpg","test5.jpg","test6.jpg"];
        var image = 1;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            console.log("scrolled");
            windowScrollCount   = $(this).scrollTop();
            animationFrame      = (windowScrollCount / 8);

            animationFrame = Math.floor(animationFrame % imageArr.length);
            console.log(animationFrame + " : " + windowScrollCount);
            $('.walk').attr("src", imageArr[animationFrame]);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried an alternative way with css, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uauszv0k/1/). anyway, @11thdimension 's answer seems better :)